# Should we have a "clone" or "deep copy" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was going to tag [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/259145/14625) with either "clone" or "deep copy" or "deep clone" but it appears we have no such tag.

If as a community we feel this tag is worth creating, then I would go ahead with that.

I feel we need it because

- It is a common (hard) topic in programming, and many people write their own
- I found 84 hits on [deep clone](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=deep+clone), 397 hits on [deep copy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=deep+copy)

Comment: Why not just create the tag? When it comes to tagging, if you have the reputation for it, it's sort of expected for you to classify questions using tags in a way that makes them more searchable, and organized. Creating tags that instill order is a right, perhaps even a responsibility of high-rep users, and it's why we have that permission. You don't need to ask a meta question to get permission for it, you have the permission already (and, in fact, you can earn badges for it, and get rewarded for it). Meta is only really used for cleaning up bad or obsolete tags.

Comment: The hit counts suggest "deep-copy" should be the primary name - suggest "deep-clone" as an alias?

Comment: @rolfl If anyone hasn't used a privilege before and doesn't know 'the correct way'; IMO asking on meta should be allowed and encouraged.
Worst case we can say 'we trust you to do what you think is best'.
Best case we can stop someone doing something inappropriate (however uncommon).
And in both cases we won't be setting up a situation where people can't ask for help, and so won't use privileges out of fear of 'doing something wrong'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the data:

> I found 84 hits on "deep clone", 397 hits on "deep copy"

That suggests you should create [deep-copy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-copy).  You should be able to suggest [deep-clone](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-clone) as a synonym, once the first exists.

Please be gentle when adding the new tag to existing questions - try not to swamp the "active questions" list, because doing so can crowd out questions that deserve notice.